# using paypal IPN with php

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

EDIT: i understand what an undefined variable is, not the problem. Why does the paypal IPN that i found in their documentation not defining the variable

```html
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
```

i have been trying to setup a donation button on my website. I have turned on the IPN at paypal and setup a sandbox. What i would like it to do is: send the user to paypal with a donation amount via this donation button:

```html
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

After the donation was made i of course want a confirmation from paypal that it has been completed. As i understand for that i need to use the IPN.

So i found this guide hence my new IPN file is:

```
<?php
session_start();
// STEP 1: read POST data
// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
    // read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
    $ch = curl_init('https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
    // In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
    // please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set
    // the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
    if ( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
        // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);


    // inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // The IPN is verified, process it
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
    }

    // inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // The IPN is verified, process it:  
        // check whether the payment_status is Completed
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // process the notification
        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        echo $payment_status;

        $_SESSION['payment_status'] = $payment_status;

    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
        echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
    }
?>
```

And after the donation is successful I set in paypal to send to this page:

success.php

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['payment_status'];

?>
```

And when testing it with a successful donation, i get an error:

> undefined index 'payment_status'

Is it because i messed something up at the IPN or?

Comment: So you never reached the code that set `$_SESSION['payment_status'];`

Comment: I did not understand what you mean, why does it not reach it?

Comment: If that session variable is not set then you never executed the code that sets it. So look at your code and work out why you are not executing the code that sets the session

Comment: That is exactly my question, i dont understand why it does not set